# What's the best way to share images between users in a mobile application?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating a simple application where users can create wishlists, which is then stored in a mysql database. These wishlists contains an image of the item they want. What is the best way to go about sharing images between users? I couldn't find any good tutorials on how to use Android studio + mysql to share images, and most of the answers I see online are to "store only the path to the image in the database", but doesn't this mean you would have to store the images in the application itself, so the application would get larger and larger in size every time a user adds an image to a wishlist?

Would it be best to use an API (maybe Imgur?) to host the image, then retrieve the link, and store that link in the mysql database?
Or maybe use a different kind of database, like firebase?

Please let me know if anyone here has done something similar in the past :)
I'm open for any type of suggestion!

I figured I'd mention I code in Kotlin, but answers in Java are also much appreciated, as it's easy to convert :)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to go about sharing images between users?

Kind of depends on what you mean by "sharing images between users". Like do you want one user to share an image from their wishlist to another user? Or do you mean that you want your app to re-use the same image between different users of the app so you don't waste space duplicating the image?

> I couldn't find any good tutorials on how to use Android studio + mysql to share images, and most of the answers I see online are to "store only the path to the image in the database", but doesn't this mean you would have to store the images in the application itself, so the application would get larger and larger in size every time a user adds an image to a wishlist?

No. Photos are generally stored in shared, external directories, so then you only need the path / URI to that location in your application. Of course, then you have to handle the case that the image goes missing, moves, or gets deleted since you have no control over the file itself.

See the documentation for more:

- https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics
- https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics

> Would it be best to use an API (maybe Imgur?) to host the image, then retrieve the link, and store that link in the mysql database? Or maybe use a different kind of database, like firebase?

"Best" would be subjective and a matter of opinion. It really depends on your app and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi! For the wish list application, I invite other users to a wish list. This wish list contains different items, like maybe a football, new shirt, new pants, etc. These items contain a Title, description and an Image. When another user views that wish list, they see all items with names, description and images. My preferred approach would be to store the image in a MYSQL database, like I do with the title and description, but so far I haven't made much progress :)

Comment: From this comment it does sound like you'd want to store these images on a server somewhere, which is again a matter of opinion on how to do that.
**I haven't made much progress** - please post code that shows what are you are doing and what is not working.

Comment: The point of this post isn't to improve on my existing code. Imagine I'm starting blank today. I want some pointers to videos, tutorials, or just some quick description on how other people solved the problem of sharing images between users

Comment: Everything you just listed is available to you by searching the internet using your favorite search engine. SO is a question and answer site, not an opinion site. Note that "the problem of sharing images between users" continues to be a vague description as it's unclear what you mean by "sharing". Again, it sounds like you need a backend for your app and there are plenty of options for you experiment with, like Firebase, which you already mentioned.